# Flexbox SVG is not inlined with other elements

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I am trying align svg and few li elements inline which are wrapped by flexbox container.For some reason last svgs are not inlined with others.
CSS:

```
.container{
    margin-left:20px;
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.logo{
    width: auto;
    fill:orange;
    height: 57px;
}
.menu{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: space-between;
}
.menu li {
    padding:30px;
    list-style: none;
}
.secondmenu{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.secondmenu  svg{
    padding: 10px;

    width: 3%;
  }
```

Here is the codepen with html:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eboMOQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go lastpeony4 cleaned up your code a little bit this should get you started.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmeWBO?editors=1100

```
.container{
    margin-left:20px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.logo{
    width: auto;
    fill:orange;
    height: 57px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;

}

ul li {
  padding: 1rem
}

.svg-container {
  display: flex;
}

.svg-container svg {
  height: 20px;
    padding: 1.8rem 1rem;
}
```

Comment: hello what if i make font larger how to align them again inline ? because for example if i add fontSize to ul menu slightly goes down

Comment: you can adjust the padding on .svg-container svg... the height controls the size of the icon and the padding 1.8rem (top and bottom) 1rem (left and right) if you need them to be close together so you can better align them just comment out flex-grow: 1; on the ul untill you are satisfied let me know if you need anything else.  Thank you for the answer mark

Comment: Also if you would like to get rid of the padding all together look into align items and justify content for flexbox.  Then you would need to supply your ul and svg-container with some sort of width and height (min-width / min-height or just width / height) then align items center and justify content space around / space between

Answer (score 1):

to place the whole menu in one line:

you just need in to change in your `.container` `flex-wrap` from `wrap` to `nowrap`

```
.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  fill: orange;
  height: 57px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

.secondmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.secondmenu svg {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 99 58">
 <path d="M11.9 49.6c-2.1 0-4.2-.7-5.8-2.2A8.2 8.2 0 0 1 3 41.6c0-.2 0-.4-.1-.6V24.7s4.1 0 4.1 3.7v4.7l.6-.3c.1 0 .1-.1.1-.1.1 0 .2-.1.2-.1a8.2 8.2 0 0 1 4.2-1.1h.4c1.9.1 3.5.6 5 1.7 2.1 1.6 3.3 3.6 3.7 6 .3 2.1 0 4.1-1 5.8-1.5 2.5-3.5 4-6.2 4.5-.8 0-1.5.1-2.1.1zm.2-14.3c-.3 0-.6 0-.9.1-2.6.3-4.2 2.4-4.2 5v.4c0 1.5.6 2.7 1.7 3.6.9.8 2.2 1.3 3.4 1.3.9 0 1.9-.3 2.7-.7 1.9-1.1 2.7-2.9 2.4-5.2-.3-2.2-2.1-4.5-5.1-4.5zM69.1 49.6c-2.4 0-4.7-.9-6.5-2.7a8.78 8.78 0 0 1-2.7-6c-.1-2.5.7-4.9 2.5-6.7 1.8-1.8 4.1-2.9 6.7-2.9 5 0 9.2 4.1 9.2 9.1 0 2.4-.9 4.6-2.6 6.4a9.13 9.13 0 0 1-6.1 2.8h-.5zm.1-14.3c-.3 0-.6 0-1 .1a5.1 5.1 0 0 0-4.3 5.2v.4c.1 2.8 2.3 4.9 5.1 4.9.9 0 1.9-.3 2.7-.7 1.9-1.1 2.6-2.9 2.3-5.2-.1-2.5-2-4.7-4.8-4.7zM40.2 24.7v24.6h4.3V28.4c-.1-3.6-4.3-3.7-4.3-3.7zM46.4 24.7v24.6h4.3V28.4c0-3.9-4.3-3.7-4.3-3.7z"></path>
 <path d="M52.6 49.3v-2.7-6.4c0-1.4.1-2.9.7-4.4.9-2.1 2.5-3.3 4.7-4 1.8-.5 3.4-.4 3.4-.4v3.9s-1 0-2 .3c-1.4.4-2.3 1.3-2.5 2.8-.1.6-.2 1.4-.2 2.2v8.7h-4.1zM79.9 51.7c1.8 0 2.3.9 2.7 1.3.6.5 1.4.8 2.1.8 2.3 0 4.1-2.1 4.1-4.1v-.9c-1 .6-2.1.8-3.2.8-4.1 0-7.3-3.4-7.3-7.6V31.6h4.1v10.2c0 1.9 1.5 3.6 3.2 3.6 1.9 0 3.2-1.6 3.2-3.6v-6.5c0-3.7 4.1-3.7 4.1-3.7v18c0 4.2-3.1 8.1-8.2 8.1-3.1 0-5.9-1.8-7.1-4.7-.4-.8-.5-1.4-.5-1.4s1.3.1 2.8.1zM30.3 45.9c-1.7 0-3.1-.8-4-2l13-4.6c-.6-3-1.8-4.9-3.6-6.2a9.3 9.3 0 0 0-7-1.5c-.6.1-1 .2-1.6.4a8.96 8.96 0 0 0-5.8 9.3 9 9 0 0 0 3.2 6.2c1.8 1.5 4 2.2 6.3 2.2 1 0 1.9-.2 2.9-.6 3.7-1.3 5.4-4.1 5.8-6.7h-2.4c-1.5 0-2.1 1-2.5 1.4a5.94 5.94 0 0 1-4.3 2.1zm-1.7-10.3c.1 0 .1 0 .2-.1H29.1c.4-.1.8-.2 1.3-.2.9 0 1.8.3 2.6.7.4.2.7.5 1 .8V37.1l.4.4-9.2 3.2v-.5c.1-2.2 1.4-3.9 3.4-4.6zM75.6 5.5c-.7 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3 0 .7.7 1.4 1.5 1.2.3 1.1.9 2.1 1.8 2.8l.4.2.4-.3c.7-.6 1.4-1.7 1.7-2.8h.3c.7 0 1.3-.6 1.3-1.3s-.7-1.2-1.4-1.2c-.8 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3 0 .9-.5 2.1-1.1 2.9-.6-.7-1-1.8-1.1-2.9.1-.6-.5-1.2-1.2-1.2zm16.5 11.6c-2.5-6.2-6.1-8-7.6-8.6.1-.4.1-.7.1-1.2 0-3.6-3-6.5-6.6-6.5-3.5 0-6.3 2.8-6.8 6.4-.7 8.7 5 13.5 7.8 15.7 1.6 1.2 2.4 2.1 1.5 3.6-.6.8-1.2 2-1.8 2.2-1.6.3-2.1 1.3-2.1 1.3H78c1.8 0 2.3-.1 4.1-3 1.7-2.9-1-4.5-2.1-5.4-2.8-2.1-8-6.4-7.3-14.2v-.1c.3-3 2.5-5.2 5.4-5.2a5.16 5.16 0 0 1 3.7 8.8c-.9 1-2.2 1.5-3.6 1.5-.5 0-.9-.1-1.3-.2-1.4-.4-2 .6-2 .6l-.1.1.1.1c.9.6 2.2.9 3.3.9 1.8 0 3.4-.6 4.6-1.9.6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.4-2 1.2.5 4.4 2.1 6.7 7.7.6 1.4 1.1 2.8 1.6 4-1.8 0-8.1-.2-11.2-5.1-.8-1.3-2.1-1-2.1-1 3.2 7.7 12.3 7.5 14 7.6.8 2 1.5 3.6 1.8 4.5-.7 0-2.1-.3-3.7-1.7a7.11 7.11 0 0 0-5.1-1.9l-4 6.3s1.9 0 2.7-1.2l2.2-3.5c1.1.1 2.2.6 3.3 1.5 2.1 1.7 3.4 1.9 4.7 1.9 1.2.1 1.9-.3 1.9-.3s-2.4-5.6-4.9-11.7z"></path>
 </svg>
  <div class="menu">

    <li>
      <a>
    <span>SHOP</span>
</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
    <span>BUNDLES</span>
</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
    <span>EXPLORE</span>
    </a>
    </li>


  </div>




  <nav class="secondmenu">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M15.5,26.8c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.1-0.6C13.1,24.1,6.7,14,6.7,9.5c-0.1-5,3.8-9.1,8.8-9.3c1.1,0,2.2,0.2,3.2,0.7
        L19.1,1c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.6,1.6,1l0.3,0.3c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.4,0.7,0.9,1,1.4L23,4.7c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4
        s0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4l0.2,0.4l0.2,0.4c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.9s0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0.1,0.5,0.2,1.1,0.2,1.6l0,0v0.3c0,1.2-0.3,2.4-0.7,3.5
        c-0.2,0.5-0.4,1.1-0.6,1.6c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.7-0.5,1l-0.3,0.7L21.8,17l-0.3,0.7c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.4-1.1,2c-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.9-0.7,1.3
        L19,22.2l-0.3,0.6c-1.2,2-2,3.3-2.1,3.4C16.4,26.6,16,26.8,15.5,26.8L15.5,26.8z M15.5,2.8c-3.6,0.1-6.3,3.1-6.2,6.7
        c0,2.7,3.6,9.4,6.2,13.6l1-1.6l0.3-0.5c0.2-0.4,0.5-0.8,0.7-1.2s0.5-0.8,0.7-1.2c0.4-0.7,0.7-1.3,1-2c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7
        l0.3-0.7l0.3-0.6c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.4-1c0.2-0.5,0.4-1,0.6-1.5c0.3-0.9,0.6-1.8,0.6-2.7V9.3c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.2
        c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3s-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6l-0.1-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3S21,6.4,21,6.3S20.9,6.1,20.8,6l-0.1-0.1
        c-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-0.7-1c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.6l-0.2-0.2c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.5-1.2-0.8l-0.3-0.1C17,2.9,16.3,2.8,15.5,2.8z
         M15.5,13.4c-2.6-0.1-4.6-2.2-4.6-4.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.1-2.6,2-4.7,4.5-4.8l0,0c2.6,0,4.7,2.2,4.7,4.8c0,0,0,0,0,0
        C20.1,11.1,18.1,13.3,15.5,13.4L15.5,13.4z M15.5,6.4c-1.2,0.1-2,1.1-2,2.2c-0.1,1.2,0.8,2.2,2,2.2c1.2-0.1,2.1-1.1,2-2.2
        C17.6,7.4,16.7,6.4,15.5,6.4C15.5,6.3,15.5,6.3,15.5,6.4L15.5,6.4z"></path>
       </svg>







    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M15.3,15.7c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.2L2,6.5C1.4,6.1,1.3,5.3,1.7,4.7S2.9,4,3.5,4.4l11.9,8.5l12.1-8.5
        C28,4,28.8,4.1,29.2,4.7c0.4,0.6,0.3,1.4-0.3,1.8l0,0l-12.8,9C15.9,15.6,15.6,15.7,15.3,15.7z"></path>
       <path  d="M27.3,6.3c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1V21c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1H3.7c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1V6.5
        c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1H27.3 M27.3,3.8H3.7C2.2,3.8,1,5,1,6.5V21c0,1.5,1.2,2.7,2.7,2.7h23.6c1.5,0,2.7-1.2,2.7-2.7V6.5
        C30,5,28.8,3.8,27.3,3.8L27.3,3.8z"></path>
       </svg>






    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M8.1,16.6c3,3,7.9,3,11,0s3-7.9,0-11s-7.9-3-11,0c-1.4,1.5-2.3,3.4-2.3,5.5C5.8,13.2,6.6,15.2,8.1,16.6z
        M27.8,23.5c0.5,0.5,0.5,1.3,0,1.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.5,0.5-1.3,0.5-1.8,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-6-6c-4.5,3.5-11,2.7-14.6-1.8
       c-1.4-1.8-2.2-4.1-2.2-6.5c0-5.7,4.6-10.4,10.4-10.4C19.3,0.8,24,5.4,24,11.1c0,2.3-0.8,4.5-2.2,6.4L27.8,23.5z"></path>
      </svg>











    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
        <path  d="M24,18.8H10.3c-0.6,0-1.1-0.4-1.3-0.9L5.5,6.1L5.1,4.8c-0.3-1-1.1-1.6-2.1-1.7H1.3C0.6,3.2,0,2.7-0.1,2
         s0.5-1.3,1.2-1.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0h1.6c2.1,0,3.9,1.4,4.6,3.4L8,5.2l0.3,1h21c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.3,1L30,14
         C29.6,16.9,27,19,24,18.8z M11.2,16.3H24c3.1,0,3.4-2.4,3.5-2.5l0.4-4.9H9L11.2,16.3z"></path>
        <path  d="M13.6,27c-1.8,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.2c0-1.8,1.4-3.2,3.2-3.2s3.2,1.4,3.2,3.2c0,0,0,0,0,0C16.7,25.6,15.3,27,13.6,27
         C13.6,27,13.6,27,13.6,27z M13.6,23.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0
         C14.2,23.5,13.9,23.2,13.6,23.2z"></path>
        <path  d="M25.3,27c-1.8,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.1c0-1.8,1.4-3.2,3.1-3.2c1.8,0,3.2,1.4,3.2,3.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
         C28.4,25.6,27,27,25.3,27z M25.3,23.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6s0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6
         C25.9,23.5,25.6,23.2,25.3,23.2z"></path>
       </svg>







  </nav>


</div>
```

**edit to comment**: in order to have svg's the same size, you need to add a a fixed width to `.logo` and `.secondmenu svg`:

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  fill: orange;
  height: auto;
  min-width:75px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top:-16px;
width: 35px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  border:1px solid gold;

}

.menu li {
  padding: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

.secondmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
border:1px solid navy;
}

.secondmenu svg {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 99 58">
 <path d="M11.9 49.6c-2.1 0-4.2-.7-5.8-2.2A8.2 8.2 0 0 1 3 41.6c0-.2 0-.4-.1-.6V24.7s4.1 0 4.1 3.7v4.7l.6-.3c.1 0 .1-.1.1-.1.1 0 .2-.1.2-.1a8.2 8.2 0 0 1 4.2-1.1h.4c1.9.1 3.5.6 5 1.7 2.1 1.6 3.3 3.6 3.7 6 .3 2.1 0 4.1-1 5.8-1.5 2.5-3.5 4-6.2 4.5-.8 0-1.5.1-2.1.1zm.2-14.3c-.3 0-.6 0-.9.1-2.6.3-4.2 2.4-4.2 5v.4c0 1.5.6 2.7 1.7 3.6.9.8 2.2 1.3 3.4 1.3.9 0 1.9-.3 2.7-.7 1.9-1.1 2.7-2.9 2.4-5.2-.3-2.2-2.1-4.5-5.1-4.5zM69.1 49.6c-2.4 0-4.7-.9-6.5-2.7a8.78 8.78 0 0 1-2.7-6c-.1-2.5.7-4.9 2.5-6.7 1.8-1.8 4.1-2.9 6.7-2.9 5 0 9.2 4.1 9.2 9.1 0 2.4-.9 4.6-2.6 6.4a9.13 9.13 0 0 1-6.1 2.8h-.5zm.1-14.3c-.3 0-.6 0-1 .1a5.1 5.1 0 0 0-4.3 5.2v.4c.1 2.8 2.3 4.9 5.1 4.9.9 0 1.9-.3 2.7-.7 1.9-1.1 2.6-2.9 2.3-5.2-.1-2.5-2-4.7-4.8-4.7zM40.2 24.7v24.6h4.3V28.4c-.1-3.6-4.3-3.7-4.3-3.7zM46.4 24.7v24.6h4.3V28.4c0-3.9-4.3-3.7-4.3-3.7z"></path>
 <path d="M52.6 49.3v-2.7-6.4c0-1.4.1-2.9.7-4.4.9-2.1 2.5-3.3 4.7-4 1.8-.5 3.4-.4 3.4-.4v3.9s-1 0-2 .3c-1.4.4-2.3 1.3-2.5 2.8-.1.6-.2 1.4-.2 2.2v8.7h-4.1zM79.9 51.7c1.8 0 2.3.9 2.7 1.3.6.5 1.4.8 2.1.8 2.3 0 4.1-2.1 4.1-4.1v-.9c-1 .6-2.1.8-3.2.8-4.1 0-7.3-3.4-7.3-7.6V31.6h4.1v10.2c0 1.9 1.5 3.6 3.2 3.6 1.9 0 3.2-1.6 3.2-3.6v-6.5c0-3.7 4.1-3.7 4.1-3.7v18c0 4.2-3.1 8.1-8.2 8.1-3.1 0-5.9-1.8-7.1-4.7-.4-.8-.5-1.4-.5-1.4s1.3.1 2.8.1zM30.3 45.9c-1.7 0-3.1-.8-4-2l13-4.6c-.6-3-1.8-4.9-3.6-6.2a9.3 9.3 0 0 0-7-1.5c-.6.1-1 .2-1.6.4a8.96 8.96 0 0 0-5.8 9.3 9 9 0 0 0 3.2 6.2c1.8 1.5 4 2.2 6.3 2.2 1 0 1.9-.2 2.9-.6 3.7-1.3 5.4-4.1 5.8-6.7h-2.4c-1.5 0-2.1 1-2.5 1.4a5.94 5.94 0 0 1-4.3 2.1zm-1.7-10.3c.1 0 .1 0 .2-.1H29.1c.4-.1.8-.2 1.3-.2.9 0 1.8.3 2.6.7.4.2.7.5 1 .8V37.1l.4.4-9.2 3.2v-.5c.1-2.2 1.4-3.9 3.4-4.6zM75.6 5.5c-.7 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3 0 .7.7 1.4 1.5 1.2.3 1.1.9 2.1 1.8 2.8l.4.2.4-.3c.7-.6 1.4-1.7 1.7-2.8h.3c.7 0 1.3-.6 1.3-1.3s-.7-1.2-1.4-1.2c-.8 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3 0 .9-.5 2.1-1.1 2.9-.6-.7-1-1.8-1.1-2.9.1-.6-.5-1.2-1.2-1.2zm16.5 11.6c-2.5-6.2-6.1-8-7.6-8.6.1-.4.1-.7.1-1.2 0-3.6-3-6.5-6.6-6.5-3.5 0-6.3 2.8-6.8 6.4-.7 8.7 5 13.5 7.8 15.7 1.6 1.2 2.4 2.1 1.5 3.6-.6.8-1.2 2-1.8 2.2-1.6.3-2.1 1.3-2.1 1.3H78c1.8 0 2.3-.1 4.1-3 1.7-2.9-1-4.5-2.1-5.4-2.8-2.1-8-6.4-7.3-14.2v-.1c.3-3 2.5-5.2 5.4-5.2a5.16 5.16 0 0 1 3.7 8.8c-.9 1-2.2 1.5-3.6 1.5-.5 0-.9-.1-1.3-.2-1.4-.4-2 .6-2 .6l-.1.1.1.1c.9.6 2.2.9 3.3.9 1.8 0 3.4-.6 4.6-1.9.6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.4-2 1.2.5 4.4 2.1 6.7 7.7.6 1.4 1.1 2.8 1.6 4-1.8 0-8.1-.2-11.2-5.1-.8-1.3-2.1-1-2.1-1 3.2 7.7 12.3 7.5 14 7.6.8 2 1.5 3.6 1.8 4.5-.7 0-2.1-.3-3.7-1.7a7.11 7.11 0 0 0-5.1-1.9l-4 6.3s1.9 0 2.7-1.2l2.2-3.5c1.1.1 2.2.6 3.3 1.5 2.1 1.7 3.4 1.9 4.7 1.9 1.2.1 1.9-.3 1.9-.3s-2.4-5.6-4.9-11.7z"></path>
 </svg>
  <div class="menu">

    <li>
      <a>
    <span>SHOP</span>
</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
    <span>BUNDLES</span>
</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
    <span>EXPLORE</span>
    </a>
    </li>


  </div>




  <nav class="secondmenu">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M15.5,26.8c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.1-0.6C13.1,24.1,6.7,14,6.7,9.5c-0.1-5,3.8-9.1,8.8-9.3c1.1,0,2.2,0.2,3.2,0.7
        L19.1,1c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.6,1.6,1l0.3,0.3c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.4,0.7,0.9,1,1.4L23,4.7c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4
        s0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4l0.2,0.4l0.2,0.4c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.9s0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0.1,0.5,0.2,1.1,0.2,1.6l0,0v0.3c0,1.2-0.3,2.4-0.7,3.5
        c-0.2,0.5-0.4,1.1-0.6,1.6c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.7-0.5,1l-0.3,0.7L21.8,17l-0.3,0.7c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.4-1.1,2c-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.9-0.7,1.3
        L19,22.2l-0.3,0.6c-1.2,2-2,3.3-2.1,3.4C16.4,26.6,16,26.8,15.5,26.8L15.5,26.8z M15.5,2.8c-3.6,0.1-6.3,3.1-6.2,6.7
        c0,2.7,3.6,9.4,6.2,13.6l1-1.6l0.3-0.5c0.2-0.4,0.5-0.8,0.7-1.2s0.5-0.8,0.7-1.2c0.4-0.7,0.7-1.3,1-2c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7
        l0.3-0.7l0.3-0.6c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.4-1c0.2-0.5,0.4-1,0.6-1.5c0.3-0.9,0.6-1.8,0.6-2.7V9.3c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.2
        c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3s-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6l-0.1-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3S21,6.4,21,6.3S20.9,6.1,20.8,6l-0.1-0.1
        c-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-0.7-1c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.6l-0.2-0.2c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.5-1.2-0.8l-0.3-0.1C17,2.9,16.3,2.8,15.5,2.8z
         M15.5,13.4c-2.6-0.1-4.6-2.2-4.6-4.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.1-2.6,2-4.7,4.5-4.8l0,0c2.6,0,4.7,2.2,4.7,4.8c0,0,0,0,0,0
        C20.1,11.1,18.1,13.3,15.5,13.4L15.5,13.4z M15.5,6.4c-1.2,0.1-2,1.1-2,2.2c-0.1,1.2,0.8,2.2,2,2.2c1.2-0.1,2.1-1.1,2-2.2
        C17.6,7.4,16.7,6.4,15.5,6.4C15.5,6.3,15.5,6.3,15.5,6.4L15.5,6.4z"></path>
       </svg>







    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M15.3,15.7c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.2L2,6.5C1.4,6.1,1.3,5.3,1.7,4.7S2.9,4,3.5,4.4l11.9,8.5l12.1-8.5
        C28,4,28.8,4.1,29.2,4.7c0.4,0.6,0.3,1.4-0.3,1.8l0,0l-12.8,9C15.9,15.6,15.6,15.7,15.3,15.7z"></path>
       <path  d="M27.3,6.3c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1V21c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1H3.7c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1V6.5
        c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1H27.3 M27.3,3.8H3.7C2.2,3.8,1,5,1,6.5V21c0,1.5,1.2,2.7,2.7,2.7h23.6c1.5,0,2.7-1.2,2.7-2.7V6.5
        C30,5,28.8,3.8,27.3,3.8L27.3,3.8z"></path>
       </svg>






    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M8.1,16.6c3,3,7.9,3,11,0s3-7.9,0-11s-7.9-3-11,0c-1.4,1.5-2.3,3.4-2.3,5.5C5.8,13.2,6.6,15.2,8.1,16.6z
        M27.8,23.5c0.5,0.5,0.5,1.3,0,1.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.5,0.5-1.3,0.5-1.8,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-6-6c-4.5,3.5-11,2.7-14.6-1.8
       c-1.4-1.8-2.2-4.1-2.2-6.5c0-5.7,4.6-10.4,10.4-10.4C19.3,0.8,24,5.4,24,11.1c0,2.3-0.8,4.5-2.2,6.4L27.8,23.5z"></path>
      </svg>











    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31 27" xml="preserve">
        <path  d="M24,18.8H10.3c-0.6,0-1.1-0.4-1.3-0.9L5.5,6.1L5.1,4.8c-0.3-1-1.1-1.6-2.1-1.7H1.3C0.6,3.2,0,2.7-0.1,2
         s0.5-1.3,1.2-1.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0h1.6c2.1,0,3.9,1.4,4.6,3.4L8,5.2l0.3,1h21c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.3,1L30,14
         C29.6,16.9,27,19,24,18.8z M11.2,16.3H24c3.1,0,3.4-2.4,3.5-2.5l0.4-4.9H9L11.2,16.3z"></path>
        <path  d="M13.6,27c-1.8,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.2c0-1.8,1.4-3.2,3.2-3.2s3.2,1.4,3.2,3.2c0,0,0,0,0,0C16.7,25.6,15.3,27,13.6,27
         C13.6,27,13.6,27,13.6,27z M13.6,23.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0
         C14.2,23.5,13.9,23.2,13.6,23.2z"></path>
        <path  d="M25.3,27c-1.8,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.1c0-1.8,1.4-3.2,3.1-3.2c1.8,0,3.2,1.4,3.2,3.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
         C28.4,25.6,27,27,25.3,27z M25.3,23.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6s0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6
         C25.9,23.5,25.6,23.2,25.3,23.2z"></path>
       </svg>







  </nav>


</div>
```

Comment: they are not inlined  logo and menu are now smaller in size ??

Comment: you can fix this adding a fixed width to `.logo` and `.secondmenu svg`, I've update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem occurs because of your viewbox settings on your SVGs. You should always specify the viewport (width and height) of your SVG when using viewbox. These settings really need to be played around with to get the right effect you're looking for. I removed your 3% width and padding settings on your second menu items because they were interfering with your viewbox as well.

For your container flexbox, I changed the display to flex instead of inline-flex, and then set your seconds menu nav to margin-left of auto - This keeps it on the right of the screen.

Run the snippet and expand it to see the second menu line up the way you want. Because your icons are of a fixed width, setting the container to flex-wrap: nowrap will keep your items from wrapping, but your main icon will shrink on smaller screens.

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  fill: orange;
  height: 57px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

.secondmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.secondmenu svg {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="2 -10 100 100">
 <path d="M11.9 49.6c-2.1 0-4.2-.7-5.8-2.2A8.2 8.2 0 0 1 3 41.6c0-.2 0-.4-.1-.6V24.7s4.1 0 4.1 3.7v4.7l.6-.3c.1 0 .1-.1.1-.1.1 0 .2-.1.2-.1a8.2 8.2 0 0 1 4.2-1.1h.4c1.9.1 3.5.6 5 1.7 2.1 1.6 3.3 3.6 3.7 6 .3 2.1 0 4.1-1 5.8-1.5 2.5-3.5 4-6.2 4.5-.8 0-1.5.1-2.1.1zm.2-14.3c-.3 0-.6 0-.9.1-2.6.3-4.2 2.4-4.2 5v.4c0 1.5.6 2.7 1.7 3.6.9.8 2.2 1.3 3.4 1.3.9 0 1.9-.3 2.7-.7 1.9-1.1 2.7-2.9 2.4-5.2-.3-2.2-2.1-4.5-5.1-4.5zM69.1 49.6c-2.4 0-4.7-.9-6.5-2.7a8.78 8.78 0 0 1-2.7-6c-.1-2.5.7-4.9 2.5-6.7 1.8-1.8 4.1-2.9 6.7-2.9 5 0 9.2 4.1 9.2 9.1 0 2.4-.9 4.6-2.6 6.4a9.13 9.13 0 0 1-6.1 2.8h-.5zm.1-14.3c-.3 0-.6 0-1 .1a5.1 5.1 0 0 0-4.3 5.2v.4c.1 2.8 2.3 4.9 5.1 4.9.9 0 1.9-.3 2.7-.7 1.9-1.1 2.6-2.9 2.3-5.2-.1-2.5-2-4.7-4.8-4.7zM40.2 24.7v24.6h4.3V28.4c-.1-3.6-4.3-3.7-4.3-3.7zM46.4 24.7v24.6h4.3V28.4c0-3.9-4.3-3.7-4.3-3.7z"></path>
 <path d="M52.6 49.3v-2.7-6.4c0-1.4.1-2.9.7-4.4.9-2.1 2.5-3.3 4.7-4 1.8-.5 3.4-.4 3.4-.4v3.9s-1 0-2 .3c-1.4.4-2.3 1.3-2.5 2.8-.1.6-.2 1.4-.2 2.2v8.7h-4.1zM79.9 51.7c1.8 0 2.3.9 2.7 1.3.6.5 1.4.8 2.1.8 2.3 0 4.1-2.1 4.1-4.1v-.9c-1 .6-2.1.8-3.2.8-4.1 0-7.3-3.4-7.3-7.6V31.6h4.1v10.2c0 1.9 1.5 3.6 3.2 3.6 1.9 0 3.2-1.6 3.2-3.6v-6.5c0-3.7 4.1-3.7 4.1-3.7v18c0 4.2-3.1 8.1-8.2 8.1-3.1 0-5.9-1.8-7.1-4.7-.4-.8-.5-1.4-.5-1.4s1.3.1 2.8.1zM30.3 45.9c-1.7 0-3.1-.8-4-2l13-4.6c-.6-3-1.8-4.9-3.6-6.2a9.3 9.3 0 0 0-7-1.5c-.6.1-1 .2-1.6.4a8.96 8.96 0 0 0-5.8 9.3 9 9 0 0 0 3.2 6.2c1.8 1.5 4 2.2 6.3 2.2 1 0 1.9-.2 2.9-.6 3.7-1.3 5.4-4.1 5.8-6.7h-2.4c-1.5 0-2.1 1-2.5 1.4a5.94 5.94 0 0 1-4.3 2.1zm-1.7-10.3c.1 0 .1 0 .2-.1H29.1c.4-.1.8-.2 1.3-.2.9 0 1.8.3 2.6.7.4.2.7.5 1 .8V37.1l.4.4-9.2 3.2v-.5c.1-2.2 1.4-3.9 3.4-4.6zM75.6 5.5c-.7 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3 0 .7.7 1.4 1.5 1.2.3 1.1.9 2.1 1.8 2.8l.4.2.4-.3c.7-.6 1.4-1.7 1.7-2.8h.3c.7 0 1.3-.6 1.3-1.3s-.7-1.2-1.4-1.2c-.8 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3 0 .9-.5 2.1-1.1 2.9-.6-.7-1-1.8-1.1-2.9.1-.6-.5-1.2-1.2-1.2zm16.5 11.6c-2.5-6.2-6.1-8-7.6-8.6.1-.4.1-.7.1-1.2 0-3.6-3-6.5-6.6-6.5-3.5 0-6.3 2.8-6.8 6.4-.7 8.7 5 13.5 7.8 15.7 1.6 1.2 2.4 2.1 1.5 3.6-.6.8-1.2 2-1.8 2.2-1.6.3-2.1 1.3-2.1 1.3H78c1.8 0 2.3-.1 4.1-3 1.7-2.9-1-4.5-2.1-5.4-2.8-2.1-8-6.4-7.3-14.2v-.1c.3-3 2.5-5.2 5.4-5.2a5.16 5.16 0 0 1 3.7 8.8c-.9 1-2.2 1.5-3.6 1.5-.5 0-.9-.1-1.3-.2-1.4-.4-2 .6-2 .6l-.1.1.1.1c.9.6 2.2.9 3.3.9 1.8 0 3.4-.6 4.6-1.9.6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.4-2 1.2.5 4.4 2.1 6.7 7.7.6 1.4 1.1 2.8 1.6 4-1.8 0-8.1-.2-11.2-5.1-.8-1.3-2.1-1-2.1-1 3.2 7.7 12.3 7.5 14 7.6.8 2 1.5 3.6 1.8 4.5-.7 0-2.1-.3-3.7-1.7a7.11 7.11 0 0 0-5.1-1.9l-4 6.3s1.9 0 2.7-1.2l2.2-3.5c1.1.1 2.2.6 3.3 1.5 2.1 1.7 3.4 1.9 4.7 1.9 1.2.1 1.9-.3 1.9-.3s-2.4-5.6-4.9-11.7z"></path>
 </svg>
  <div class="menu">

    <li>
      <a>
        <span>SHOP</span>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span>BUNDLES</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span>EXPLORE</span>
      </a>
    </li>


  </div>


  <nav class="secondmenu">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M15.5,26.8c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.1-0.6C13.1,24.1,6.7,14,6.7,9.5c-0.1-5,3.8-9.1,8.8-9.3c1.1,0,2.2,0.2,3.2,0.7
        L19.1,1c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.6,1.6,1l0.3,0.3c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.4,0.7,0.9,1,1.4L23,4.7c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4
        s0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4l0.2,0.4l0.2,0.4c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.9s0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0.1,0.5,0.2,1.1,0.2,1.6l0,0v0.3c0,1.2-0.3,2.4-0.7,3.5
        c-0.2,0.5-0.4,1.1-0.6,1.6c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.7-0.5,1l-0.3,0.7L21.8,17l-0.3,0.7c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.4-1.1,2c-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.9-0.7,1.3
        L19,22.2l-0.3,0.6c-1.2,2-2,3.3-2.1,3.4C16.4,26.6,16,26.8,15.5,26.8L15.5,26.8z M15.5,2.8c-3.6,0.1-6.3,3.1-6.2,6.7
        c0,2.7,3.6,9.4,6.2,13.6l1-1.6l0.3-0.5c0.2-0.4,0.5-0.8,0.7-1.2s0.5-0.8,0.7-1.2c0.4-0.7,0.7-1.3,1-2c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7
        l0.3-0.7l0.3-0.6c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.4-1c0.2-0.5,0.4-1,0.6-1.5c0.3-0.9,0.6-1.8,0.6-2.7V9.3c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.2
        c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.3s-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6l-0.1-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3S21,6.4,21,6.3S20.9,6.1,20.8,6l-0.1-0.1
        c-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-0.7-1c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.6l-0.2-0.2c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.5-1.2-0.8l-0.3-0.1C17,2.9,16.3,2.8,15.5,2.8z
         M15.5,13.4c-2.6-0.1-4.6-2.2-4.6-4.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.1-2.6,2-4.7,4.5-4.8l0,0c2.6,0,4.7,2.2,4.7,4.8c0,0,0,0,0,0
        C20.1,11.1,18.1,13.3,15.5,13.4L15.5,13.4z M15.5,6.4c-1.2,0.1-2,1.1-2,2.2c-0.1,1.2,0.8,2.2,2,2.2c1.2-0.1,2.1-1.1,2-2.2
        C17.6,7.4,16.7,6.4,15.5,6.4C15.5,6.3,15.5,6.3,15.5,6.4L15.5,6.4z"></path>
       </svg>







    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M15.3,15.7c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.2L2,6.5C1.4,6.1,1.3,5.3,1.7,4.7S2.9,4,3.5,4.4l11.9,8.5l12.1-8.5
        C28,4,28.8,4.1,29.2,4.7c0.4,0.6,0.3,1.4-0.3,1.8l0,0l-12.8,9C15.9,15.6,15.6,15.7,15.3,15.7z"></path>
       <path  d="M27.3,6.3c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1V21c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1H3.7c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1V6.5
        c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1H27.3 M27.3,3.8H3.7C2.2,3.8,1,5,1,6.5V21c0,1.5,1.2,2.7,2.7,2.7h23.6c1.5,0,2.7-1.2,2.7-2.7V6.5
        C30,5,28.8,3.8,27.3,3.8L27.3,3.8z"></path>
       </svg>






    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml="preserve">
       <path  d="M8.1,16.6c3,3,7.9,3,11,0s3-7.9,0-11s-7.9-3-11,0c-1.4,1.5-2.3,3.4-2.3,5.5C5.8,13.2,6.6,15.2,8.1,16.6z
        M27.8,23.5c0.5,0.5,0.5,1.3,0,1.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.5,0.5-1.3,0.5-1.8,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-6-6c-4.5,3.5-11,2.7-14.6-1.8
       c-1.4-1.8-2.2-4.1-2.2-6.5c0-5.7,4.6-10.4,10.4-10.4C19.3,0.8,24,5.4,24,11.1c0,2.3-0.8,4.5-2.2,6.4L27.8,23.5z"></path>
      </svg>











    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml="preserve">
        <path  d="M24,18.8H10.3c-0.6,0-1.1-0.4-1.3-0.9L5.5,6.1L5.1,4.8c-0.3-1-1.1-1.6-2.1-1.7H1.3C0.6,3.2,0,2.7-0.1,2
         s0.5-1.3,1.2-1.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0h1.6c2.1,0,3.9,1.4,4.6,3.4L8,5.2l0.3,1h21c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.3,1L30,14
         C29.6,16.9,27,19,24,18.8z M11.2,16.3H24c3.1,0,3.4-2.4,3.5-2.5l0.4-4.9H9L11.2,16.3z"></path>
        <path  d="M13.6,27c-1.8,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.2c0-1.8,1.4-3.2,3.2-3.2s3.2,1.4,3.2,3.2c0,0,0,0,0,0C16.7,25.6,15.3,27,13.6,27
         C13.6,27,13.6,27,13.6,27z M13.6,23.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0
         C14.2,23.5,13.9,23.2,13.6,23.2z"></path>
        <path  d="M25.3,27c-1.8,0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.1c0-1.8,1.4-3.2,3.1-3.2c1.8,0,3.2,1.4,3.2,3.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
         C28.4,25.6,27,27,25.3,27z M25.3,23.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.6c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6s0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6
         C25.9,23.5,25.6,23.2,25.3,23.2z"></path>
       </svg>







  </nav>

</div>
```